# Javascript regex: Choose substring without specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out the regular expression, that will match substring beginning with '<' and ending with "/>".

I don't want to match substring with '>' in other place than the end of a string.

Input string:

```
...<Tree Name=\"Normal tree\" TreeTemplateId=\"0\"><Group ColumnName=\"Normal column\" /></Tree>...
```

Desired output:

```
<Group ColumnName=\"Normal column\" /></Tree>
```

I tried this:

```
/<(.*?)\/>/g
```

But result string was:

```
<Tree Name=\"Normal tree\" TreeTemplateId=\"0\"><Group ColumnName=\"Normal column\" /></Tree>
```

Is possible to do it in javascript with regular expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presuming this is valid XML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: No, unfortunately, input string is not valid XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to catch the `Group` tag?

```
var str = "<Tree Name=\"Normal tree\" TreeTemplateId=\"0\"><Group ColumnName=\"Normal column\" /></Tree>";
var matches = str.match(/<[^<]+\/>/);
console.log(matches[0]);
```

Prints:

```
<Group ColumnName="Normal column" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this is  what I was looking for!